# Как взять хеш-состояние формы?

Tags: jquery, javascript

На странице есть форма с полями. По клику на элемент вне формы нужно взять хеш-состояние формы, для того чтобы после внесения изменений в форму выдать сообщение пользователю, что форма изменена.

В случае, если хеш начальной формы отличается от хеша второй формы.
Иными словами, нужно отследить изменение формы.

Comment: `jQuery.fn.serialize` + `JSON.stringify` ?

Comment: Возможно, т.е. просто сериализовать форму и сравнивать, как строки?

Comment: Попробуйте.